# TypeORM inserting Geometry type with ST_GeomFromGeoJSON

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a postgres table who is using `Geometry` column type.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE areas (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    polygon GEOMETRY
);
```

And, normally I was inserting data like:

```
INSERT INTO areas (name, polygon) VALUES (
    'A',
    ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON ((-123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065, 
                        -123.11882257461549 49.28074038150665, 
                        -123.11337232589727 49.27721276406796, 
                        -123.1078577041626 49.281104327676616, 
                        -123.10996055603025 49.28152426222755, 
                        -123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065))'));
```

And currently is working properly if I run the statement from postgres.

But in my NestJS/TypeORM entity I have defined:

```
@Column('geometry', {nullable: true, name: 'polygon ' }
@ApiProperty()
polygon : string;
```

And once I assign the value with:

areas .polygon = 'POLYGON ((-123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065,
-123.11882257461549 49.28074038150665,
-123.11337232589727 49.27721276406796,
-123.1078577041626 49.281104327676616,
-123.10996055603025 49.28152426222755,
-123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065))';

I get this error:

> error: error: unknown GeoJSON type
> at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\myuserpath\myproject\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:278:15)

But I notice the raw query is:

```
INSERT INTO "areas VALUES ('A', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('POLYGON ((-123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065, 
                            -123.11882257461549 49.28074038150665, 
                            -123.11337232589727 49.27721276406796, 
                            -123.1078577041626 49.281104327676616, 
                            -123.10996055603025 49.28152426222755, 
                            -123.11386585235593 49.284015800344065)))'::geometry)
```

I'm not sure where the column has defined `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`
How can insert that polygon using TypeORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long research, I found a way to do it.
There is another way to perform an insertion:

```
const myPolygon = [[-123.11882257461549 49.28074038150665],[...],[...],[...]]

    const areas = await getConnection()
          .createQueryBuilder()
          .insert()
          .into(Areas) //HERE YOUR TABLE NAME
          .values({
            name: 'MrMins',
            columnX: 'lorem ipsum', //LIST OF YOUR COLUMNS
            active: true, //LIST OF YOUR COLUMNS
            polygon: () =>
              `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON( '{ "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [${myPolygon}] }' )`,
          })
          .execute();
```

The entity is declared as in the question. But this way to perform an `Insert` you can use any function you want: `ST_GeometryFromText` or even if you are using `POINT`.

Comment: Would this technique protect execution against SQL injection?

Comment: You need to normalize your geoJSON object first

Answer (score 2):

I found just having the entity's column annotated as follows with standard mutations on your resolver:

```
   @Column({
        type: 'geometry',
        spatialFeatureType: 'LineString',
        srid: 4326,
    })
```

I prefer this approach over using querybuilder, and when you query, you get your data already formatted as the text/JSON form of the geometry.

Comment: But doesn't it require you to store a geometry as text (WKT) in database?

Comment: @jayaro Yes, but you can use TypeOrm transformer to use the data in the format you need in your code.